# Is hitting the side of the table legal?

Tags: rules, table-tennis

In table tennis, on the rare occasion when the ball makes it over the net but hits the **side of the table** rather than on top (which is pretty hard to counter), Is this a valid point?

Comment: How can the ball go over the net and then come down and hit the side of the table but not the top?

Comment: @BenMiller, When enough players know how to put spin on the ball, easily.

Comment: Ultimately -- no matter how it happens -- a ball that hits the side of the table, **is out**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

International Table Tennis Federation (ITTF) [rules in regards to the table](http://www.ittf.com/ittf_handbook/ittf_hb.html) go to 2.01 ("The Table"), or playing surface are fairly straightforward and short. A ball is **in play** if it touches any part of the **top** of the table.

> 2.01.02   The playing surface shall not include the vertical sides of the tabletop.

Therefore, anything not considered the "top" surface of the table would be **out** and the point would then end. So in your case, I assume someone went to the side of the table to return a hit, and it struck the side of the opponent's table (or as the ITTF refers to it "the vertical sides of the tabletop"). This hit would be **out**.

[image: ITTF Table Rules]

[<sub>(Bigger Image)</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1lis.png)

Comment: @echad - Play daily at work, so we're constantly verifying rules after we play to prove one another wrong :-)